# Curl POST, how to do it in Corona

Tags: curl, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to figure out how to use this curl post which works in the cmd line, in my Corona made app:

```
curl --user access_key:secret_key -X POST -d "username=user1&email=someone@mail.com&password=password" http://ccs-core-env-xejfmg7sfn.elasticbeanstalk.com//users.json
```

My problem is definitely the 2 keys. I have tried sending a network request like this:

```
local params = {}
local headers = {}

headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

local body = "username=user1&email=someone@mail.com&password=password"
params.headers = headers
params.body = body

network.request( "http://ccs-core-env-xejfmg7sfn.elasticbeanstalk.com/users.json",   "POST", networkListener, params )
```

Where I have tried sending these 2 keys as headers and also included them in the params, but always get the response,  HTTP Basic: Access Denied

Does anyone know the correct way that I can post these keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires HTTP authorization. I think you should add "Authorization" HTTP field. The Authorization field value consists of credentials
      containing the authentication information of the user agent for
      the realm of the resource being requested

Comment: Example of Authorization field:Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==